# Adding extra regressor in Prophet

Tags: percentage, facebook-prophet

I hope I'll find a way to ask a question. I have data of a store's income with a 3-4 year history. My goal is to forecast next two months. I'm trying to achieve this with prophet, and so far it's going well. I have a regressor I want to use to improve my forecast but I'm not sure how to use it the best way I can. My regresor is different levels of impact on the stores income where 1 equals no impact, and 1,20 for example equals, 20 percent increase on that day. 0,8 would mean that there would be 20 percent decrease on income. How could I fit that kind of information in the best way to my model?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Should be straight forward. You'd  use the add_regressors() function, documented [here](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/seasonality,_holiday_effects,_and_regressors.html#additional-regressors). If you have your regression term (a column say 'impact') at the same time series level, you'd add it (in R) by doing:

```
m <- prophet()
add_regressor(m = m, 
              name = 'impact')
m <- fit.prophet(m = m, df = <your_dataframe_here>)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the trick is the assignment before add_regressor command below. Otherwise, add_regressor() adds a regressor to m but, it isn't saved. m isn't passed by reference. You should assign it to m to make it effective.

Let's say that you have a CSV for cars sold and Google Trends point for search volume:

```
2011-01-01;18;6410
2011-02-01;21;8120
2011-03-01;24;10620
2011-04-01;21;12283
2011-05-01;18;13318
```

R code:

```
cars = read.csv('cars.csv', sep=';', header=FALSE)
colnames(cars) <- c("month", "search", "sales")
cars$date <- as.Date(cars$month, "%Y-%m-%d")

dfx <- data.frame(cars$date, cars$sales, cars$search)
colnames(dfx) <- c("ds", "y", "search")
head(dfx)

m <- prophet()
m <- add_regressor(m = m, name = 'search')
m <- fit.prophet(m = m, df = dfx)
```

Don't forget to write m <- add_regressor (...)